# Linear Search Code in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is linear search code but it is not working can anyone help me out!!

```
data = []
n = int(raw_input('Enter how many elements you want: '))
for i in range(0, n):
    x = raw_input('Enter the numbers into the array: ')
    data.append(x)

print(data)

def lSearch(data, s):
    for j in range(len(data)):
        if data[j] == s:
            return j
    return -1

s = int(input('Enter the element do you want to search: '))
result = lSearch(data, s)

if result == -1:
    print("The Element is not found")
else:
    print("The element is an array at index %d",result)
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Are there errors?

Comment: You could just do `for j, el in enumerate(data): if el == s: return j`

Comment: Are you sure this is python3? `raw_input` doesn't exist in Python 3 - it's a Python 2 equivalent of `input()`

Comment: @SumnerEvans, but if you need to return the index? usually use `enumerate()` there

Comment: Don't return -1 when `s` is not found; raise an exception!

Comment: @chepner Actually the normal `str.find()` function returns `-1` when an item is not found. Error raising is generally a bad idea if you don't know what your list contains

Answer (score 4):

`s` is an integer, but your list will be full of strings since you append `x` to it.

```
x = raw_input('Enter the numbers into the array: ')
```

See here `x` is a string. You have not converted this to an int (unlike at other places)

---

If this is actually Python 3 and not Python 2 (as it says in your tags), then you should be using `input()` not `raw_input()` (raw_input doesn't actually exist in Python 3). `input()` will return a string in Python 3 (unlike in python2, where it might return an integer).

Answer (score -2):

thanks to everyone.Now , my code is running by a simple change raw_input to input().
data = []

n = int(input('Enter how many elements you want: '))

for i in range(0, n):

```
x = input('Enter the numbers into the array: ')

data.append(x)
```

k = sorted(data)

print(k)

def lSearch(k, s):

```
for j in range(len(k)):

    if k[j] == s:

        return j

return -1
```

s = int(input('Enter the element do you want to search: '))

result = lSearch(k, s)

if result == -1:

```
print("The Element is not found")
```

else:

```
print("The element is an array at index %d",result)
```

Comment: No, you don't want to switch `raw_input` to `input` if you are in Python 2.

Comment: This is only working by accident, and that accident is a potential security problem if you were to use similar code in a real application.